# how to use onClickListener with my own class

Tags: java, android, class, onclicklistener, android-snackbar

I have created my own class to mimick the Snackbar, lets call it CustomSnackbar.  What I am trying to achieve is to customize the snackbar and be able to call CustomSnackbar from my main activity and for the usage to be very similar to calling the standard Snackbar. For the purpose of demonstrating my example without all the bulk code, here is my CustomSnackbar class:

```
package com.wizzkidd.myapp.helpers;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomSnackbar {

    Context _context;
    Snackbar snackbar;

    public CustomSnackbar(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public void make(View view, CharSequence text, int duration) {
        snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "", duration);

        Snackbar.SnackbarLayout snackbarLayout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();

        TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarLayout.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //hide the default snackbar textview


        //Create my own textview instead
        TextView myTextView = new TextView(_context);
        myTextView.setText(text);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); //Create layout params for some text
        myTextView.setLayoutParams(params); //Apply the text layout params

        snackbarLayout.addView(myTextView); //Add my text to the main snackbar layout.  (Other widgets will also be added)
    }

    public void setAction(CharSequence text) {
        snackbar.setAction(text, new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //do something
                Log.v("TAG", "You clicked the action");
            }
        });
    }

    public void show() {
        snackbar.show();
    }
}
```

In my MainActivity, I am using the class like this:

```
CustomSnackbar customSnackbar = new CustomSnackbar(activity);
customSnackbar.make(view, "This is my snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
customSnackbar.setAction("HIDE");
customSnackbar.show();
```

You can see that I am using my .setAction method to pass a string/charsequence but I am unsure how to handle the onClickListener in the same call instead of handling the onClickListener inside the class

Please ignore the fact that the class may appear pointless (but this is because I have simplified it for the purpose of this question).  I'm not sure that I am creating this class correctly, so any additional advice or suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare somewhere else your `OnClickListener`, e.g. in `Activity` in which you are calling your methods, and pass it to your class

```
final View.OnClickListener ocl = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //do something
            Log.v("TAG", "You clicked the action");
        }
}
CustomSnackbar customSnackbar = new CustomSnackbar(activity);
customSnackbar.make(view, "This is my snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
customSnackbar.setAction("HIDE", ocl);
customSnackbar.show();
```

and inside your custom class:

```
public void setAction(CharSequence text, final View.OnClickListener ocl) {
    snackbar.setAction(text, ocl);
}
```

now inside `OnClickListener` you may call methods from `Activity`

Comment: Thank you.  From your example I can clearly see what I was missing, and how simple it was to resolve.

Comment: As an extension to my question (not sure how to put this into SO the correct way), how do I go about mimicking the Snackbar classes other methods.  Should I be extending the Snackbar class from my CustomSnackbar class?  If so do you have an example where I would need to override the .make method to suit me.  Does that make sense?

Comment: your current code looks like simple "Helper", which keeps some static methods out of your "main code" like `Activity`. it's just an approach you picked and it's fine. you may also extend original `SnackBar`, then you should put your code from currently named "make" method to constructor or any other method inside which you will be shure that `SnackBar`s layout is already implemented. I don't now your whole idea (like you said, you cutted some code). In my opinion "Helper" version may be more convienient and you can also provide additional `getOriginalSnackBar()` method with `return snackbar;`

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right.  It is acting as a simple Helper class and fits my purpose without too much code.  I don't need to over complicate this unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

you have to provide it as parameter to your `setAction` method. E.g.

```
public void setAction(CharSequence text, final View.OnClickListener listener) {
```

and either pass the provided instance, or proxy the call to the other object

Answer (score 1):

Do a class extends Snackbar.

Then addMouseListener(classWithExtendedSnackbar)

Answer (score 0):

I am exactly not clear about your question. But,if you want to make a custom Snackbar which will display all your message, and give functionality on click of it. Then you can try this code.

just call this method to make a snackbar.

```
//Here I am sending one as code
showMessage("Snackbar Opened","Close",1)

//send different code based on which you can set something to be done, or identify a button click

private void showMessage(String msg, String action_name, final int code) {
    progress.cancel();
    final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    snackbar.setAction(action_name, new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            clearDataForListView();
            if (code == 1) {
               //do something if code is one/if a particular button is clicked

               //you can dismiss anwhere else also.
               snackbar.dismiss();
            } else if (code == 2) {
               //do something if another button is pressed
               snackbar.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    snackbar.show();
}
```